# Discrete Mathematic Group Theory

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group consisting of the identity element 1, an element $a$, and some other elements.

Show that if $a^3 = 1$   then $a$ has a square root in $G$, i.e., that there is some $r$ in $G$ for which $a = r^2$.

I think i should use the identity  there is an element e in G such that
e * x = x * e = x 
Like a*a^(3) = 1 not sure??

Comment: The identity element has been given to be $e= 1$ (see your first sentence.) If $a^3 = 1$, provided $a\neq 1$. That means the order of $a$ is $3$, and that $a$ generates the cyclic subgroup $\langle a \rangle =\{1, a, a^2\} $, with $a^3 = 1, \;a^4 = a, \;a^5 = a^2,$ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  What can you say about the square of $a^2$?